# Does Huggingface's "resume_from_checkpoint" work?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I currently have my trainer set up as:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=f"./results_{model_checkpoint}",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    push_to_hub=True,
    save_total_limit = 1,
    resume_from_checkpoint=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_qa["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_qa["validation"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=DataCollatorForMultipleChoice(tokenizer=tokenizer),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
```

After training, in my `output_dir` I have several files that the trainer saved:

```
['README.md',
 'tokenizer.json',
 'training_args.bin',
 '.git',
 '.gitignore',
 'vocab.txt',
 'config.json',
 'checkpoint-5000',
 'pytorch_model.bin',
 'tokenizer_config.json',
 'special_tokens_map.json',
 '.gitattributes']
```

From the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer.train.resume_from_checkpoint) it seems that `resume_from_checkpoint` will continue training the model from the last checkpoint:

`resume_from_checkpoint (str or bool, optional) — If a str, local path to a saved checkpoint as saved by a previous instance of Trainer. If a bool and equals True, load the last checkpoint in args.output_dir as saved by a previous instance of Trainer. If present, training will resume from the model/optimizer/scheduler states loaded here.`

But when I call `trainer.train()` it seems to delete the last checkpoint and start a new one:

```
Saving model checkpoint to ./results_distilbert-base-uncased/checkpoint-500
...
Deleting older checkpoint [results_distilbert-base-uncased/checkpoint-5000] due to args.save_total_limit
```

Does it really continue training from the last checkpoint (i.e., 5000) and just starts the count of the new checkpoint at 0 (saves the first after 500 steps -- "checkpoint-500"), or does it simply not continue the training? I haven't found a way to test it and the documentation is not clear on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it works! When you call trainer.train() you're implicitly telling it to override all checkpoints and start from scratch. You should call trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=True) or set resume_from_checkpoint to a string pointing to the checkpoint path.

Comment: will this also work if previously saved checkpoints were created by a script with trainer.train(), and now I changed the script to  trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=True)  and run it?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, it first [loads the checkpoint state](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/d0acc9537829e7d067edbb791473bbceb2ecf056/src/transformers/trainer.py#L1534), [updates how many epochs have already been run](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/d0acc9537829e7d067edbb791473bbceb2ecf056/src/transformers/trainer.py#L1535), and [continues training](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/d0acc9537829e7d067edbb791473bbceb2ecf056/src/transformers/trainer.py#L1598) from there to the total number of epochs you're running the job for (no reset to 0).

To see it continue training, increase your `num_train_epochs` before calling `trainer.train()` on your checkpoint.

Comment: I tried increasing the epochs to 220 after training it so far on 110. It still started the counter from 0 (it finished the 110 epochs on step 16500, but started from 0 for the 220 epoch call)

Answer (score 2):

You also should add resume_from_checkpoint parametr to trainer.train with link to checkpoint

> trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint="{<path-where-checkpoint-were_stored>/checkpoint-0000")

0000- example of checkpoin number.

Don't forget to mount your drive during whole this process.

Comment: link to doc https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#checkpoints

Comment: The "boolean" approach `resume_from_checkpoint=True` mentions "which will resume training from the latest checkpoint". Which unless I'm missing something implies that it will automatically use the last checkpoint, so I don't need to specify the last one with a path. Nevertheless, it doesn't really answer my question about whether it works (e.g., the counts problem)

Comment: Yes, you're rigth, they promise it to work like you said. I just wanted to make sure that trainer uses  right checkpoint, so I specified path. Idk how it works only with boolean param, try to ask on hugging face thread